# How to loop a SYS_REFCURSOR with multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle9i

sorry for the kind of broad title to the question, but I didn't find a way to simplify it further.

I'm creating a package for a client, this package has a procedure which returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. The query that feeds it is a multi-table select with about 20 fields. On a second procedure I need to call this one, and loop through the results to feed other locations.

I'm having problems using the `into` part of the loop. I can't use `table%ROWTYPE`. I tried to declare an `OBJECT` on the procedure but it was not allowed. Will I have to do a `FETCH XXX INTO LIST_OF_INDVIDUAL_VARIABLES`?

```
DECLARE
    dt_field TABLE1.dt_field%TYPE;
    p_resultset SYS_REFCURSOR;
    p_individual OBJECT ( 
     FIELD0         DATE,
     FIELD1         TABLE.FIELD1%TYPE,
     FIELD2         TABLE.FIELD2%TYPE,
     FIELD3         TABLE.FIELD3%TYPE,
     FIELD4         TABLE.FIELD4%TYPE
 );

 BEGIN
    PACKAGE.PROCEDURE1(dt_field);
    dbms_output.put_line(dt_field);
    PACKAGE.PROCEDURE2(dt_field, p_resultset);

   LOOP 
     -- this do not work
     FETCH p_resultset INTO p_individual;
     EXIT WHEN p_resultset%NOTFOUND;
     -- DO STUFF ON EACH RETURNED ROW
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE p_resultset;      
 END;
```

Comment: _"I tried to declare an OBJECT on the procedure but **it was not allowed**"_ As a result of your enterprise policy? By lack of required permissions? Or does it simply produce some kind of error?

Comment: Take a look at this answer by Alex Poole maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233929/2363712

Comment: You'd need to declare a record type in PL/SQL, not an object, and then an instance of that record type. Showing the error you get would be helpful. I'm not sure if you can fetch a ref cursor into a record type, off-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on my comment, you can't create an object type in PL/SQL, you need to declare a record type, and then an instance of that type:

```
DECLARE
  type r_individual is record (
    FIELD0         DATE,
    FIELD1         TABLE1.FIELD1%TYPE,
    FIELD2         TABLE1.FIELD2%TYPE,
    FIELD3         TABLE1.FIELD3%TYPE,
    FIELD4         TABLE1.FIELD4%TYPE
  );
  p_individual r_individual;
...
```

And you can fetch a ref cursor into a record type. Your version errors on the object declaration, not the `fetch`.

Here's a more complete example based on what's in your question; I don't have your procedures so I'm creating a dummy result set with the same types, and used a dummy table for the `%TYPE` declarations:

```
create table table1(dt_field date, field1 number, field2 varchar2(1),
  field3 number, field4 varchar2(1));

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  type r_individual is record (
    FIELD0         DATE,
    FIELD1         TABLE1.FIELD1%TYPE,
    FIELD2         TABLE1.FIELD2%TYPE,
    FIELD3         TABLE1.FIELD3%TYPE,
    FIELD4         TABLE1.FIELD4%TYPE
  );
  dt_field TABLE1.dt_field%TYPE;
  p_resultset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  p_individual r_individual;

BEGIN
  -- Don't have this package
  -- PACKAGE.PROCEDURE1(dt_field);
  -- dbms_output.put_line(dt_field);
  -- PACKAGE.PROCEDURE2(dt_field, p_resultset);

  -- Dummy result set for demo instead
  OPEN p_resultset FOR q'[select sysdate, 1, 'A', 3, 'C' from dual]'
    || q'[ union all select sysdate, 2, 'B', 4, 'D' from dual]';

  LOOP 
    FETCH p_resultset INTO p_individual;
    EXIT WHEN p_resultset%NOTFOUND;
    -- DO STUFF ON EACH RETURNED ROW
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_individual.field1
      || ':' || p_individual.field2);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE p_resultset;
END;
/
```

Which gets:

```
anonymous block completed
1:A
2:B
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that was exactly where I failed. Moving from MySQL\MariaDB is a big endeavor. Still trying to find my way.

Comment: Appears : expression 'P_INDIVIDUAL' in the INTO list is of wrong type

Comment: @delive - appears where? This code runs without error in SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer, again 11g and 12c. What is the full ORA- or PLS- error message? Or is your client/IDE generating that itself? If you have a problem this doesn't fix, you'll need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Alex Poole the error appears in FETCH p_resultset INTO p_individual; I have multiples tables and I get this error. For example you have in this code "TABLE1."  I have "TABLE1." "TABLE2." "TABLE3." with rowtype

Comment: @delive - then you haven’t adapted this to match your query properly. Like I said, ask a new question, showing your tables, your version of the code and the issues you are having.